# Can' fix screen tearing on Ubntu 20.04

Tags: nvidia, asus, 20.04, nvidia-optimus

I just installed Ubuntu 20.04 on my Asus ROG GL752VW-DH71, and I can't seem to fix Ubuntu's screen tearing issue. `sudo lspci | grep VGA && sudo lshw -c video | grep configuration && glxinfo | grep -i vendor` returns:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 530 (rev 06)
       configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
server glx vendor string: SGI
client glx vendor string: Mesa Project and SGI
    Vendor: Intel (0x8086)
OpenGL vendor string: Intel
```

`ubuntu-drivers devices` returns the following:

```
== /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.0/0000:02:00.0 ==
modalias : pci:v00008086d0000095Asv00008086sd00005010bc02sc80i00
vendor   : Intel Corporation
model    : Wireless 7265 (Dual Band Wireless-AC 7265)
manual_install: True
driver   : backport-iwlwifi-dkms - distro free

== /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.0 ==
modalias : pci:v000010DEd0000139Bsv00001043sd00001D6Dbc03sc02i00
vendor   : NVIDIA Corporation
model    : GM107M [GeForce GTX 960M]
driver   : nvidia-driver-435 - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-390 - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-440 - distro non-free recommended
driver   : xserver-xorg-video-nouveau - distro free builtin
```

[I tried following this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oYWer86A20s) tutorial that worked for me on Ubuntu 18.04, but doesn't on Ubuntu 20.04. A big part of that problem is NVIDIA X Server Settings isn't showing me any other options other than selecting my PRIME Profile. All it shows is:

```
Select the GPU you would like to user
    NVIDIA (Performance Mode)
    NVIDIA On-Demand
    Intel (Power Saving Mode)
```

The first one (`NVIDIA (Performance Mode)`) is pre-selected, but I don't have any of the other X Server Settings options I used to have.

Anybody know what could be up? Is this a new thing in 20.04?

Comment: Did you try lowering the "Refresh rate" of the display in the system settings? What is it now?

Comment: @SergeyK Yes I tried that, too. No dice...

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it! I had to `sudo apt-get purge nvidia-settings` and then reinstall it. I now have all the options and was able to use the tutorial I linked and now its working!